# Which framework /Platform do I have to create interactive ebooks + videos?

Tags: ebook

im sorry if its not fit to this forum , but say I like to create interactive ebook , what I mean is 
Digital book like ordinary ebook but with options to show videos and be able to validate readers excises .
I guess such thing will have somekind of pre scripting options to me to define rules . 
Is there such tool ?

Comment: What formats do you want to create / what systems should it be able to run on?

Comment: i guess it can only be exe file , systems for start windows